# Error Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported en SpringBoot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, postman, microservices

Estoy haciendo un pequeño ejemplo de Login con Angular y SpringBoot y al enviar los datos en el login, me sale ese error en el log del back

> Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

Y en el navegador (Chrome) en la consola

> POST http://localhost:8080/login 415 exception ocurred

En mi back tengo el siguiente código
Controller

```html
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    
    @PostMapping(value ="/login", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @CrossOrigin(origins= "http://localhost:4200")
    public Login loginUser(@RequestBody Login login ) {
        String usuario = login.getUsuario();
        String pssd = login.getPassword();
        System.out.println("PRUEBA DATOS: " +usuario + pssd);
        Login log = null;
        if(usuario != null && pssd != null) {
            
            log = loginService.datosUsuario(usuario, pssd);
            System.out.println("PRUEBA LOG " +log.toString());
        }
        return log;
    }
    
}
```

Entidad

```html
@Entity
@Table(name="login")
public class Login implements Serializable {

    
    
        /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4229514279685470669L;

        @Id
        @Column 
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int idlogin;

        @Column 
        private String nombre;
        @Column 
        private String password;
        @Column 
        private String usuario;

        
        public int getIdlogin() {
            return idlogin;
        }

        public void setIdlogin(int idlogin) {
            this.idlogin = idlogin;
        }

        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getUsuario() {
            return usuario;
        }

        public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
            this.usuario = usuario;
        }

        

}
```

Y en mi front Angular html

```html
<div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
    <div id="formContent">
      <form #loginform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="loginUser()">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <input type="text" id="usuario" class="form-control" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" [(ngModel)]="login.usuario">
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="login.password">
        <br>
        <button  class="btn btn-primary">Acceder</button>
      </form>
  
    </div>
</div>
```

mi component.app

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import { Login } from 'src/app/Modelo/Login';
import { ServiceLoginService } from 'src/app/Service/service-login.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  login = new Login();
  constructor(private service: ServiceLoginService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  loginUser(){
    this.service.loginUserFromRemote(this.login).subscribe(
      data => console.log("response recieved"),
      error => console.log("exception ocurred")
    )
  }

}
```

mi service

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Login } from '../Modelo/Login';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceLoginService {

 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public loginUserFromRemote(usuario:Login):Observable<any>{
   return this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:8080/login", Login)
  }
  

}
```

A que se debe que me este saliendo ese error?, ¿es tema del backend?
Trate quitando el **consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE** y nada, trate cambiarlo a **TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE** y nada, y cuando hago pruebas en POSTMAN sí me funciona, selecciono el body, raw, y JSON y si funciona.
¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Tienes una errata: `this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:8080/login", Login)` debería ser `this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:8080/login", usuario)`

Comment: gracias, si era eso